# Calling a function that is a clock from within another function accelerates the clock

Tags: javascript

I have three function: the first is a clock with setTimeout within, the second is a function called when the clock reach zero with a setInterval within and the third is a function called when the setInterval of the second is cleared and set another interval that when is cleared call the clock again. The chain of functions work but accelerate the clock a lot and I don't know why.

```
    var secs=8;
    function clock(){
       secs--;
       var timer=setTimeout(clock,1000);
       document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = 'Clock: ' + secs;
       if(secs==0){
               clearTimeout(timer);
               noEvent();
             }
       }

    function noEvent(){
            var count=10;
            var timer1=setInterval(function(){
                    // do something
            count--;

            if(count==0){
              clearInterval(timer1);
              repetition();
                  }
              },200)
     }

    function repetition(){
           var count=3;
           var timer2=setInterval(function(){
                    // do something
           count--;

           if(count==0){
                   clearInterval(timer2);
                   secs=8;
                   clock();
                       }
           },1000)
    }


  var index=0;
  $("myId").click(function(){
     var rand=this.id;
     var check=(arrComputer[index]==rand); // arrComputer is an array 
                                          // generated by the computer
                                          // by other function

     if(check==true) {
            // do something
            clock();
                }     

  }
```

The functions and the calls work but the clock that is set to 1 second (setTimeout(clock,1000)) go to one second in the first call, but in successives go much faster, so the variable secs go 8,7,6,5,...,0 but to a bigger speed: between 8 and 7 there is not 1000ms but may be 200ms.

Comment: I changed your code to a snippet and added an output element to see what's going on.  It seems to work ok though, it's not displaying the problem you mentioned, can you confirm?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. I do know that `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are asynchronous and you're changing a global variable within them, which is a recipe for race conditions...

Comment: I was missing a click event that produces the acceleration. I edited the code with the new lines for the click. When clicking it checks if the value of 'this' is the same of one generated by the computer before. If it is and check==true the clock is called again, so for the next click there is only a few seconds. If the clock reach zero there is a call to noEvent() function.It is here where the clock accelerates and it doesn't work properly.